# How to disable blue selection on double click, in table header?

Tags: html, css

I have followed table header structure:

```
<th>
 <a ng-click="sort_by(order)" style="color: #555555;">
   <span ng-transclude="">
       <span class="ng-scope">Some text</span>
   </span>
   <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
 </a>
</th>
```

The problem is, when I double click on header link, the background is selected (blue color) and seems messy.

How to avoid this behavior?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [**`user-select:none`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), which will disable selection of the `th` element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/3dA77/) - try highlighting the element.

```
th {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Support for this property can be found [**here**.](http://caniuse.com/user-select-none)

---

If you are concerned about support, you could alternatively use [**`::selection`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection) to change the color from blue to transparent. This method has a *little* more support.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/3dA77/1/) - try highlighting the element.

```
th::selection {
    color:transparent;
}
th::-moz-selection {
    color:transparent;
}
```

It is supported in IE9. [**Reference here.**](http://caniuse.com/css-selection)

Comment: @fessy Updated with an alternative method... if you are concerned about support you would need a JS solution.

Comment: @MohsenSafari @JoshCrozier Since user-select is not available on IE9, try: `<div unselectable="on">Test Text</div>`